# how to add color field after Commerce Fancy Attributes has been installed?

Tags: commerce

In my website I used drupal commerce, and I would like to display product my its color in product display page. This is the link I reference https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes, I have successfully installed that module. That guide said create a 'Color' vocabulary, add a text field called "Color" that will hold hex values. But I can't find the 'hex' in field type. So I can't continue the next step. I would appreciate any suggestion you could give me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a simple "text field".